# Macro lens for Olympus E-3

Tags: equipment-recommendation

I am thinking of getting a macro lens. Technically, it seems, I already have one, a Sigma DC 18-50mm, but it doesn't feel like it when I try to take close ups. I have an Olympus E-3, Olympus 1.4xTeleconverter EC-14 (and fwiw, a Olympus Zuiko Digital 50-200mm). Maybe I just don't know how to use the lens I have correctly? Or if buying a lens is i order, what can you recommend?

Sigma DC 18-50mm
http://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/Sigma-18-50mm-f-2.8-EX-DC-Lens-Review.aspx

This raises another question. If Olympus is getting out of, or at least de-emphasizing, DLSR, should I, instead of buying another Olympus lens, buy another brand of body? Will my current lenses work on other brands of body?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olympus are concentrating on m4/3. While there are still 4/3 lenses available, they are mostly on online auction sites.

[Their lens lineup](http://www.four-thirds.org/en/fourthirds/lense.html) has 2 macro lenses. The [35mm f/3.5](http://asia.olympus-imaging.com/products/dslr/lenses/35_35M/) and the [50mm f/2.0](http://asia.olympus-imaging.com/products/dslr/lenses/50_20M/). The 50mm is the better, more expensive one.

*As for the Sigma 18-50mm, I haven't heard of it before. Are you able to find a link about it so I can properly compare and answer?*

The link in your answer doesn't state it is a Macro lens. Most macro lenses are a fixed focal length, also.

In regards to getting rid of the 4/3 glass, there is no need. Olympus have an adaptor for m4/3 to 4/3. The [MMF2](http://www.olympus.com.au/Products/Accessories/PEN-Adaptors-Other-Accessories/MMF-1-Lens-Adapter.aspx) and the [MMF3](http://www.olympus.com.au/Products/Accessories/PEN-Adaptors-Other-Accessories/MMF-3.aspx). The MMF3 is meant to be waterproof but there is no speed difference with these.

What makes the difference is the body. That adaptor will work on any m4/3 body. Of course designed for Olympus bodies, they will still work with Panasonic.

[The OM-D, E-M1](http://www.olympus.com.au/Products/CompactSystem-Cameras/OMD-cameras/OM-D-E-M1.aspx) was released as an alternate to the DSLR and the focussing speeds with 4/3 glass is almost on par with the E-3/5. Certainly with the E-620 and faster than the 4xx/5xx series.

That sigma is actually designed for the APS-C format (think specifically for Nikon's DX format, not Canon's APS-C format), so yes, it will work.

I guess their isn't really an answer for "Keep lens, buy body" or "Buy new lens only" as that will come down to personal preference. Research, take a look around. Try out the E-M1 body and Nikon's DX bodies and see if you can get your hands on the 50mm f/2.0.

But, both options are available.

Comment: Updated question

Comment: So what's the difference between a fixed 50mm lens and an 18-50mm lens positioned at 50?

Comment: Nothing, really. But any lens at 50mm compared to another can be different because a certain lens can hold different characteristics and have different minimum/maximum apertures. But the difference between a Macro 50mm and a standard 50mm is the focussing distance. [Macro lenses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macro_photography) have a much closer focusing distance and are generally a fixed focal length (doesn't zoom). That lens you have, technically is not a Macro lens.

Comment: Oh, the difference is the focussing distance, that's why I would by a fixed 50mm macro lens.

Comment: Macro lenses can come in varying focal lengths, they just generally aren't zooms. 50mm and 35mm are the only 4/3 macro lenses. Macro also just means a 1:1 reproduction image size. So, if you took a photo of a 24mmx36mm box on a 135 format camera, that box would fill the frame. The length *could* mean you are 1m away from it. But in general terms, a macro lens has close focussing distances and also aren't zooms.